# fetching tabledata in ios from oneview controller to anoher view controller

Tags: ios, iphone

Please give the suggestion of these code

**appdelegate.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "MainViewController.h"

    @interface MainAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController;
    }

    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *MainviewController;

    appdelegate.m



    #import "MainAppDelegate.h"
    #import "MainViewController.h"
    @implementation MainAppDelegate
    @synthesize  navigationController, MainviewController;
    @synthesize matri;

    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        matri=@"";
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        self.MainviewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.MainviewController animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    } //plaese provide detail of code
```

**mainviewcontroller.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "SecViewController.h"

    @interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

    mainviewcontroller.m

    #import "MainViewController.h"
    #import "MainAppDelegate.h"

    @interface MainViewController ()


    @end

    @implementation MainViewController


    {
        NSArray *tableData;
        MainAppDelegate *appDelegate;
    }
    //@synthesize pun;


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //appDelegate=(MainAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate ];

        tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
        NSLog(@"tabledata : %@", tableData);
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
         NSLog(@"tabledata : %@", tableData);
         return [tableData count];
    }


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }



        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      //  NSLog(@"Value at index:%@",cell.textLabel.text);

        return cell;

    }


     -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

         SecViewController *SecView = [[SecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecViewController" bundle:nil];
         SecView.newarray =[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:SecView animated:YES ];


    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @end
```

1. i dont understand how to call secondview from first view help me out
2. the hole code file are for creating simple table view and to call secviewcontroller
3. can anyone help me to provide code how to call secview object and how to use in mainview controller

and i also created nsmutablearray with newarray object and synthesize it 
can any one understand this code and give the brief description to that code and suggest me to what i miss sothat i can check this and call secviewcontroller from mainviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

use this code into app delegate.m file

```
    YourviewController *loginVc = [[YourviewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"YourviewController" bundle:nil];
            self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVc];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden =YES;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: what is yourviewcontrolle is it first view controller class

Comment: k i add this but i show error that loginvc are not identified

Comment: no i just add what u write with my view name

Comment: i have sent u a demo check it.

Answer (score 0):

CHeck this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        matri=@"";
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        self.MainviewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.MainviewController]; //Embedding your navigationController in mainviewcontroller
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

And then in your mainViewCOntroller.m

```
#import"appdelegate.h"
```

And then in

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

         SecViewController *SecView = [[SecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecViewController" bundle:nil];
         SecView.newarray =[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
         [delegate.navigationController pushViewController:SecView animated:YES ];


    }
```

Comment: AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] is it necessary to do

Comment: @Amit205 there is difference.. because by doing this there will be a common container of viewCOntrollers available anywhere..

Comment: @Amit205 what problem you are facing in this code.

Comment: actually i want to run my code without using AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] so i want to know is it possible to do that if yes then provide me code

Comment: yes you can use self.navigationController property but then you'll not bale to move more than one level down..

Comment: ok can u give me code

Comment: plz send me complete code for table view at amitagr04@gmail.com

Comment: Have you tried the above code..

Comment: yes bt i dont understand error can u provide me complete code

Comment: I have sent you the sample project on mail.. check it..

Comment: ya got but i want these coding with xib

Comment: Just change this line DetailVC *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailVC"];
into
DetailVC *dvc = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

Comment: far beyond nobody can help you just refer docs.. First read it and then implement.. Or you are able to understand this provided code.. Then I guess its far more than enough what anyone can do here..

Answer (score 0):

Do this one.

```
self.MainviewController  = [[MainviewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"MainviewController" bundle:nil];
            self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.MainviewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden =YES;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: ya i write exact u write

Comment: please don't post multiple answer. if you want some new changes then edit your answer....

Comment: my problem still not solve can u mail me exact code for table view in xib not in storyboard at amitagr04@gmail.com